# Calculating lim, why not infimum?

Tags: calculus, limits

why the lim of the following is 1 and not infinity when n goes to infinity?

Why I believe so?

The greatest power in numerator is -2.5 and in denominator it's 1/17 -5 since the greatest power is in the numerator then the limit is infinity

[image]

Comment: The greatest power in both numerator and denominator is zero. The resulting limit is $1/1=1$.

Comment: @M.Nestor But why? you have $n^{-2.5}$...

Comment: @BigSur $-2.5<0$.

Comment: 0k, what does that mean if it's smaller than 0

Comment: if $p<0$, then, as $n\to\infty$, $n^p\to 0$

Comment: right but why the limit here is 1/2 $n/{2n}$? since the largest power is the same then we take the arguments

Comment: when n goes to infinity then n^p is still n^p as in my example n^1 is still n^1 and not infinity....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n \to \infty$, we need to find the largest power of $n$ in the numerator and denominator. In this case, the largest power in both cases is 0 since $1 = n^0$ and all the other exponents are negative. Since the largest powers are equal, we take the ratio of the coefficients which is 1/1 = 1.